# whatsapp cloud api conversational_automation issue

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

When I query api https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/PHONE_NUMBER_ID/conversational_automation

I got error like below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Invalid edge (conversational_automation) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessAccountToNumberCurrentStatus)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AyxjH_lPsuXNVHUUid5luAj"
    }
}
```

I used permanent access token to query api.

Thanks

How to query conversational message normally use page access token?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.